# Unable to log in to Stack Exchange

Tags: support, login, openid, stackexchange.com

I can log in to Stack Exchange network sites just fine, even join new ones (like this one), but I can't log in to [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com).

- When I try any of the login methods on my Stack Overflow account, it just shows me the "this login is new" screen, even though I already have an account.
- When I try logging in with Stack Exchange, then clicking "recover my account" and entering my email (since I don't think I ever added a password, I've always logged in using Google), it just says "no account with that email was found".

Comment: When you click [this link](https://stackexchange.com/users/current), what happens? What you see?

Comment: wait what? apparently i'm logged in now, and that link shows my profile. Although I just now tried to grant an access token for a notification extension as well. Weird.

Comment: So all good now?

Comment: Yeah. Should I delete the question then? Or edit it to say what happened?

Comment: If anything, post answer with whatever solved the issue, not sure if you visiting your profile page or that token you added.

Answer (score 1):

After that, I did 2 things:

- Install the "Desktop Notifications for Stack Exchange" Chrome extension, and grant it a token. It asked me to log in, and after logging in with google, it showed me the permissions it needed. I found it odd, expecting it to ask me to create a new account, so I clicked "decline" in hopes that it hadn't really done anything yet.
- View the page https://stackexchange.com/users/current. That then showed me my profile, with all the questions I have asked and answered.

Clearly, one of these must have logged me in. I suspect it was the first.

Actually, I think that granting a token skipped the "this login is new" and created the account automatically, linking it to my profile. I thought that creating a new account would create a completely new profile, with no linked network accounts, but in reality it just linked it to my existing profile.

Comment: Well, stackexchange.com does not have its own profile since it's not a Q&A site. Instead, it shows something known as "network profile", which is the collection of all accounts one have associated across the SE network. How the login works is beyond me though.

Comment: It probably detected that my email had been used on an account already, but in that case, why did it even show the "this account is new" screen at all?

Comment: Not sure, like I said, not familiar with the internals of the login system, especially in stackexchange.com which has different code base.